# Flask error "BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand. "

Tags: python, html, flask, 400-bad-request

So, I am learning Flask and trying to create an app that will display what I typed.
Here's the python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for

app = Flask("hello")
app.secret_key = "hello"
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "This is a simple page. <p>Please navigate by yourself"


@app.route('/hi', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def inp():
    if request.method =='POST' :
        val = request.form["inpValue"]
        return render_template(url_for('rslt', res = val))
    else:
        return redirect(url_for("hello", url = "failed"))
@app.route('/<res>')
def rslt(res):
    return f"<p> Resut = {res}</p> "
app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is the index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">   
    <title>{{name}}</title>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <nav id="top">
            <input type="text" name="name">
            <p>{{name}}</p>
        </nav>
        <div id="middle">
            {% block content%}
            <form action="/hi" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="inpValue" />
                <input type="submit" value="submit" />
            </form>
            {% endblock %}
            <p>User Typed - {{inpResult}}</p>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <div id="bottom"></div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the result.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
   <p> Resut = {{result}}</p>  

</body>
</html>
```

At the end I am getting a bad request whenever I try to access the page '/hi'. Please help me rectifying my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
@app.route('/<url>')    
@app.route('/hi', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
```

The problem is that the `<url>` variable matches anything, including `/hi`.  So when you request the `/hi` page, the `/<url>` route is the first match.

Move the `/<url>` route to be **after** the `/hi` route, so it looks for `/hi` first.

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
I commented the /<URL> page, yet I am getting this error below:
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'inpValue'